# How do I replace const char* with std::string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

At first I had this which compiled fine:

```
static LISP err(const char* message, LISP x, const char* s)
{
    nointerrupt = 1;
    if NNULLP(x)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SIOD ERROR: %s %s: ",
            (message) ? message : "?",
            (s) ? s : ""
        );
        lprin1f(x, stderr);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fflush(stderr);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SIOD ERROR: %s %s\n",
            (message) ? message : "?",
            (s) ? s : ""
        );
        fflush(stderr);
    }

    if (show_backtrace == 1)
        display_backtrace(NIL);

    if (errjmp_ok == 1) { setvar(sym_errobj, x, NIL); longjmp(*est_errjmp, 1); }
    close_open_files();  /* can give clue to where error is */
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: fatal error exiting.\n", siod_prog_name);
    if (fatal_exit_hook)
        (*fatal_exit_hook)();
    else
        exit(1);
    return(NIL);
}

LISP err(const char* message, LISP x)
{
    return err(message, x, NULL);
}

LISP err(const char* message, const char* x)
{
    return err(message, NULL, x);
}
```

Then I wanted to concat another string to it, and I tried it like that:

```
LISP err(const char* message, const char* x)
{
    std::string full_message = "fromchar_" + std::string(message);
    return err(full_message.c_str(), NULL, x);
}
LISP err(const char* message, LISP x)
{
    const char* func_name = "fromlisp_";
    const char* final_message = (message) ? (func_name + std::string(message)) : "?";
    return err(final_message.c_str(), x, NULL);
}
```

This did not compile, saying that finalmessage is not of class const char*.

Somebody suggested to replace all "const char*" with "std::string".

I have tried to do that, and my functions then looked like this:

```
static LISP err(const std::string& message, LISP x, const std::string& s)
{
    nointerrupt = 1;
    if (NNULLP(x))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SIOD nullpointer error. Wir wissen aber den typ nicht: %s %s: ", message.c_str(), s.c_str());
        lprin1f(x, stderr);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fflush(stderr);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SIOD anderer error: %s %s\n", message.c_str(), s.c_str());
        fflush(stderr);
    }

    if (show_backtrace == 1)
        display_backtrace(NIL);

    if (errjmp_ok == 1) { setvar(sym_errobj, x, NIL); longjmp(*est_errjmp, 1); }
    close_open_files();  /* can give clue to where error is */
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: fatal error exiting.\n", siod_prog_name);
    if (fatal_exit_hook)
        (*fatal_exit_hook)();
    else
        exit(1);
    return(NIL);
}
LISP err(const std::string& message, LISP x)
{
    return err("error type A:" + message, x, std::string());
}

LISP err(const std::string& message, const std::string& x)
{
    return err("error type B:" + message, LISP(), x);
}
LISP err(const std::string& message, LISP x, const std::string& x_str)
{
    const std::string func_name = "error from lisp_";
    const std::string final_message = (message.empty()) ? "?" : func_name + message;
    return err(final_message, x, x_str);
}
```

However, it would not compile, saying

```
slib.cc:733:6: error: redefinition of ‘obj* err(const string&, LISP, const string&)’
  733 | LISP err(const std::string& message, LISP x, const std::string& x_str)
      |      ^~~
slib.cc:696:13: note: ‘obj* err(const string&, LISP, const string&)’ previously defined here
  696 | static LISP err(const std::string& message, LISP x, const std::string& s)
      |             ^~
~
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your updated static function defined on line 696 now has the same signature as your old adapter function defined on line 733. That's precisely what the error message is telling you. You can remove the latter, or change the name of the static function to something else like `err_private` and have all your other functions call it.

Comment: The errors you're getting are only part of the problem.  You ALSO need to ensure the pointer you return points at data that exists after the function returns.   The `std::string` named `full_message` is destroyed as the function returns, so `full_message.c_str()` is a dangling pointer for the caller of the function.   Probably easiest to simply return a `std::string`, or a structure that contains a `std::string`, instead of a `char *`  i.e. modify your `LISP` type

Comment: While that's always a consideration when using `.c_str()`, I don't think it's relevant in this case. The `LISP` type doesn't appear to store the message string.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem you encountered before you started modifying your function signatures was this:

> Then I wanted to concat another string to it, and I tried it like that:
>
> ```
> LISP err(const char* message, const char* x)
> {
>     std::string full_message = "fromchar_" + std::string(message);
>     return err(full_message.c_str(), NULL, x);
> }
> LISP err(const char* message, LISP x)
> {
>     const char* func_name = "fromlisp_";
>     const char* final_message = (message) ? (func_name + std::string(message)) : "?";
>     return err(final_message.c_str(), x, NULL);
> }
> ```
>
> This did not compile, saying that finalmessage is not of class const char*.

The main problem here is your conditional operator is not returning the same types:

```
// Error:
(message) ? (func_name + std::string(message)) : "?";
```

In the above, `func_name + std::string(message)` is of type `std::string`, whereas `"?"` is a string literal (of type `const char[2]`). The fix is to make both parts of the conditional operator return a `std::string`:

```
std::string final_message = message ? ("fromlisp_" + std::string(message)) : std::string("?");
```

And so here are your functions corrected for use with your original static `err` function:

```
LISP err(const char* message, const char* s)
{
    std::string full_message = "fromchar_" + std::string(message);
    return err(full_message.c_str(), NULL, s);
}

LISP err(const char* message, LISP x)
{
    std::string final_message = message ? ("fromlisp_" + std::string(message)) : std::string("?");
    return err(final_message.c_str(), x, NULL);
}
```

Comment: In C++14 and later, the string conversions can be simplified using `""s`, eg: `LISP err(const char* message, const char* s) { using namespace std::string_literals; return err(("fromchar_"s + message).c_str(), nullptr, s); } LISP err(const char* message, LISP x) { using namespace std::string_literals; auto final_message = message ? ("fromlisp_"s + message) : "?"s; return err(final_message.c_str(), x, nullptr); }`